# Can I get a new IP address? Is it legal?

Tags: ip, twitter

Can I get a new IP address & is it legal to ask my ISP for one or try to get a new one myself, manually? I'm unsure if twitter blocked/blacklisted my IP address. I didn't break any rules. Only 1 person I follow, who didn't block me, their tweets keep appearing then disappearing on my timeline & every time I contact twitter support, they only send me automated responses with links to resolve my issue.

Comment: Before all of that can you try twitter from a cell phone or another network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly legal to ask for a new IP address, but it's probably up to your ISP if they want to give it to you. Most ISPs (unless you've specifically asked for a static IP) will refresh your IP every few days. Try restarting your modem and/or router, sometimes that will refresh your IP address.

Since you can access Twitter, it sounds like the problem is more related to something else. Attempt it in a different browser, or, as Cory M suggested, try it from another Internet source - say, a coffee shop, a smartphone, or a proxy.

Comment: Most DHCP leases Ive seen from ISPs are 24 hours.  So turn your modem off and leave it off for at least 24 hours.

Comment: I think if I leave my cable modem off for more than a few minutes I'll lose my IP. I'll also keep it indefinitely (months at a time) as long as it stays on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly legal because your ISP owns the addresses they give you. Mediacom allows you to simply type: `ipconfig /release` then wait a few seconds and `ipconfig /renew` . I would guess that MOST ISPs will allow this type of standard DHCP requests. The benefit to doing it this way is that you don't have to wait for it to happen. Also, if your ISP is going to allow this then this is how they're probably going to have you do it anyway. If you have a static IP this will not work. That is unlikely however.

I'm purposely ignoring the Twitter part of this post. If you want me to answer something about Twitter you'll need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/index.html.en), which is an anonymizing proxy network. It will route your traffic through a series of random proxies, effectively changing your IP every time you make a connection (your original IP will never be used).

As with all proxies, you need to be cautious about what you send through Tor, as the end node (the last proxy in the chain which sends your data to its final destination) **will be able to read your data unless you use HTTPS or other end-point encryption.**

Twitter and most large websites allow you to use HTTPS these days so this shouldn't be much of a problem. Tor even has [a modified version of Firefox](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en) that should simplify the installation process.

Comment: tor is horrible for web browsing, vpn is better but since all he wants is use twitter, and i guess he visit that site few times only, since he only have 1 follower, i think tor is the best option for his situation, if he had other issues, i'd say not to use tor but a vpn

Comment: Thanks a million you guys. I searched google & found that twitter might have (Not blocked my IP), but might have blacklisted me. I tried in 3 browsers, they all do the same thing. Any idea if I do try a library or get a new IP, if twitter will still ignore my issue, because it has to do with my twitter account?

Comment: @John Have you tried to contact Twitter to solve this? If you are now sure that Twitter has blacklisted you, then they should have a good reason to do so...